# What is this arthropod?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

It is approx 2cm long and was discovered in house after a bush walk & BBQ at Riverside Garden Reserve in Mandurah, Western Australia. It has 6 legs.

Thanks! :-)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I edited your question slightly for improved readability. Please feel free to further edit.

Comment: It's almost certainly a beetle larvae/grub of some sort, but I'm afraid I don't know what species!

Comment: Lyn, I took the liberty to reedit your post to improve presentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Sawfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawfly) larvae, and is most likely of the species *Perga dorsalis* or *Perga affinis*. The larvae you depict appears to be quite young, but as it matures it'll gain a much darker color, and, depending on whether it's *P. affinis* vs. *P. dorsalis*, the abdomen will grow fairly long.

I imagine the developmental progress of your larvae is somewhere between the two following larvae.

[image]

A few more images:

[image]

[image]